# How to add dict value from a list of value python

Tags: python-3.x

i have a code like this :

```
values = [1, 'admin', 'admin123']
dict   = {'id':'', 'username':'', 'password':''}
```

i want to make it like this :

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'username': 'admin'
    'password': 'admin123'
}
```

but with for loop. not manually like :

```
{
    'id': values[0],
    'username': values[1],
    'password': values[2]  
}
```

how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```py
values = [1, 'admin', 'admin123']
dict = {'id': '', 'username': '', 'password': ''}


for k, v in zip(dict, values):
    dict[k] = v

print(dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dict.Keys()` method to get a list of all the keys. Then you can loop over them and assing values to those keys in your dictionary